# Type Head is not refreshing

Tags: javascript, typehead

Hello i am using typehead js in my project.

While i am add any new tag in my input field, it will create same name beside that tag. it is in text format not in tab format likebelow.

[image]

Please enlighten me for the same.

Thanks.!

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle version, it will be nice for us to review what going on.